# Can I port Shared library from Linux (or Windows) to Vxworks 5.5?

Tags: opengl, shared-libraries, vxworks

I am designing a set of C++ rendering APIs. All that has been done under linux and Windows platform in form of shared libraries. Now I want to port them to VxWorks (version 5.5 pretty old verion). Lots of 3rd party libs need to been ported eg. openssl, sqlit3, WxWidgets ...

My question is:

Is that possible with VxWorks 5.5 without essential changes to the code?

If it's not possible. Does any higher version of VxWorks will do ?

Does VxWorks 5.5 support shared library ?

BTW, what about OpenGL, does OpenGL require higher version of VxWorks?

Comment: First and foremost for efficient use of OpenGL you require some GPU for which drivers for VxWorks exist. You can use a software implementation of course.

Comment: On VxWorks any object file (compiled for VxWorks) is some sort of shared library since all non-static functions of the object file are added to the system symbol table and therefore are accessible to other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

First check with documentation on what all libraries are already supported and can be included in your project on VxWorks. For example we use openssl library in our project. And yes 5.5 does support shared libraries we are using libcrypto.a. Libraries which are not supported needs to be ported.

About openGL you can check this [project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mesa3d/) if it suits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can quite happily create standalone libraries for use in VxWorks 5.5, you can do it two ways, create an archive which is basically a static library which you would build into your app, or build your library as another downloadable module and when you load it in VxWorks it will dynamically link.

OpenGL version will depend on the graphics driver and hardware you have, not the version of VxWorks (other than you will need a version of the graphics driver for your version of VxWorks).

Porting 3rd party libraries is mostly ok, VxWorks is quite similar to linux in language.  The only one I know about in your list is sqlite3 which I had a go at porting a while back and it needed a little modification as some of the commands were not available in VxWorks 5.5 for creating an in memory database, but that was a long time ago now and might have changed.